# reading data with Telnet client in go

Tags: go, telnet

I'm trying to read data from some devices via telnet protocol and below is my simple code.
I just want to print some meaningful results.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/reiver/go-telnet"

)

func main() {

    conn, _ := telnet.DialTo("10.253.102.41:23")
    fmt.Println(conn)
}
```

but this is what I got by this way:
&{0xc000006028 0xc000004720 0xc000040640}

Comment: If you want to show data send by the server you should actually [read](https://godoc.org/github.com/reiver/go-telnet#Conn.Read) these. What you do here is just print the connection object.

Comment: of course, but it's not clear for me how to use it and also there isn't any example.

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that it gets you `&{0xc000006028 0xc000004720 0xc000040640}` cause you are printing the connection object and it's the pointer address of that. If you want to print the data, you have to read it through connection using the `Read` method of the connection. Something like this:

```
b := make([]byte, 100)
n, err := conn.Read(b)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

fmt.Println(string(b))
```

Comment: This is the revised code but still I can't print any data.
`code
 conn, _ := telnet.DialTo("10.253.102.41:23")
 conn.Write([]byte("test"))
 conn.Write([]byte("\n"))
 b := make([]byte, 100)
 n, err := conn.Read(b)
 if err != nil {
  // handle error
 }

 fmt.Println(string(n))

}`